# Mongoose Validation Error (in Express) returning HTML page instead of JSON response

Tags: reactjs, json, express, mongoose, error-handling

I want to fetch the error message that is returned by Mongoose, but the response I'm getting is in the form of an HTML page.

I'm using the following route handler to make a POST request:

```
app.post('/api/persons', (req, res, next) => {
    if(!req.body.name) {
        return res.status(404).json({
            error: "Name missing."
        })
    }
    else if(!req.body.number) {
        return res.status(404).json({
            error: "Number missing."
        })
    }
    else {
        const person = new Person({
            name: req.body.name,
            number: req.body.number
        })

        person.save().then(savedPerson => {
            res.json(savedPerson)
        })
        .catch(error => next(error))
    }
})
```

and the following Error Handler function:

```
const errorHandler = (error, req, res, next) => {
    console.error(error.message);

    if(error.name === 'CastError') {
        return res.status(400).send({ error: 'Malformated entry' })
    }
    else if(error.name === 'ValidationError') {
        return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Name must be at least 3 characters long.' })
    }

    next(error)
}

app.use(errorHandler)
```

The errorHandler is the last middleware to be called.

On the frontend, I'm using this to extract the error message and display it on the screen.

```
recordService.create(temp).then(response => {
        setPersons(persons.concat(response));
        setNewName("");
        setNewNumber("");
        setPersonsToShow(persons.concat(response));

        setErrorMessage(`${temp.name} has been added!`)
        setTimeout(()=>{
          setErrorMessage(null)
        }, 3000)
      }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error.response.data);
        setErrorMessage(error.response.data);
        setTimeout(()=>{
          setErrorMessage(null)
        }, 3000)
```

resordService is a module that returns axios route handler functions and create is an alias for POST.

When I display the **error.response.data**, I'm getting the following response:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>ValidationError: Person validation failed: name: Path `name` (`er`) is shorter than the minimum allowed length (3)., number: Validator failed for path `number` with value `3412`<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at model.Document.invalidate (D:\Code\WebDev\Full Stack Open\Exercises\part3\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:2948:32)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at D:\Code\WebDev\Full Stack Open\Exercises\part3\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:2737:17<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at D:\Code\WebDev\Full Stack Open\Exercises\part3\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1324:9<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:78:11)</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm only interested in the *Person validation failed: name: Path `name` (`er`) is shorter than the minimum allowed length (3)., number: Validator failed for path `number` with value `3412`* part.

How can I get the response as a JSON object?

Comment: Try to use the `message` field instead of `data`:  `setErrorMessage(error.response.message);`

Comment: try call `.end()` at `return res.status(400).json({ yourobject }).end()